# Search Food Items in laravel

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have a search box in my views and I want to search foods from the database.
My view for seach box is:

```
<div class="field" id="searchform">

<input type="text" id="searchterm" placeholder="e.g mutton 

karahi,pizza..."  />

<button type="button" id="search" 

onclick="window.location='http://localhost:8000/search'">Find Food!</button>

</div>
```

My food table has fields like:

1. Food_id
2. FoodName
3. FoodDescription
4. FoodImage
5. Price

Now I want to search my foods By name.How I can do that?plz help me.I am new to laravel and I am using laravel 5.2.

Comment: show your controllers & models code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search In Laravel

1. Create Your Model

As you mentioned you have a table say `food` we will generate a model `Food.php` in your `app` folder

```
    <?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Food extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'food';
    protected $fillable = ['id','name','description','image'];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    }
```

2. Crete a search Controller

   `php artisan make:controller SearchController`
3. Inside Controller Write logic to retrive your model records based on food name

   ```
    
    public function search(Request $request){
   $foods = Food::where('name','%LIKE%',$request->input('q'))->get();
    return view('search')->with(['foods'=>$foods]);
   }
   ```

   We are now returning our modals to view. You can use `dd($foods)` either in your controller or in view to check the results
4. In your Search Form View, make action to SearchController

   ```
   {{Form::open(array('action' => 'SearchController@search','method'=>'post','name'=>'mini_search','id'=>'mini_search','role'=>'form')) }}
   ```

   ```
       <div class="field" >

       <input type="text" id="searchterm" placeholder="e.g mutton 

       karahi,pizza..." name="q"  />

       <button type="submit" id="search" >Find Food!</button>

       </div>
      {{Form::close()}}
   ```
5. Finally, we also need a view to display our results
   SO create a file search.blade.php and display the results.
   https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#passing-data-to-views

```html
<ul>
    @foreach($foods as $food)
     <li>{{$food->name}}</li> 
    @endforeach
    </ul></pre>
```

Comment: How can we use routes to search foods?

Comment: can u explain what you want ? you can define all your routes in routes.php and map it to a controller action

Comment: I mean I add a route like this: Route::get('search', 'SearchController@search'); But it does not search foods when I enter food name in box and hit Find Foods.

Comment: have you also created that specific controller and the model as above? 
Also the method is POST so your route should be 
`Route::post('search', 'SearchController@search')`

Comment: I implement same method but it gives me blank page.Like if I search pizza and hit Find Food,a blank page opens but I want to show the details of that specific food.

Comment: have you returned the view ?? 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#passing-data-to-views
Include your code and what have you done in question. Its pretty simple and will work

Comment: Yes I returned view as : return view('search', compact('foods')); and now it gives me error "View [search] not found."

Comment: Solved the error,now how I can get the details of food in search.blade.php based on food_id.

Comment: great so far! `id` is just a param which should be returned in your collection. try `dd($foods)` in your controller / view to check

So whatever you return with `compact('foods') ` is available to view

you can try dd($foods) to see what all params are there
and if you want to display, just itereate thru params like 

`@foreach($foods as $food) 
  Id: {{$food->id}}
  name: {{$food->name}}
`  etc

Comment: still there is a blankpage after all steps

Comment: I think food_id is passed in someway so that we get the food details according to unique id of food items.like if pizza has id 1 then if we search pizza then it returns information about id 1.

Comment: can you enable error logs / check laravel.log file to see if there are any errors.. blank page shouldn't be there if you follow steps correctly
Also check for your column names and update controller / modal accordingly (my code snippet is just an example)

Comment: I remove the error and get Food Id and FoodName using @foreach as u described,but my problem is that I want to show Food items according to their Id's.As an example lets say if I enter pizza in search box and then press enter,only the details of pizza are shown to me.Similarly each food item has unique Id according to which I want to search them.

Comment: @MuhammadRamzan I believe same logic is being applied
we are getting the search term, then we are searching our food table in name column if that search term matches a record, then when we use `$foods = Food::where('name','%LIKE%',$request->input('q'))->get();` 

this line returns us every record that matches the food name. 
so yes, your record id is also there `$food->id`

now what you can do is check ur collection, and if it have only one record then instead of displaying search result view, you can directly return the item detail view 
this way you can show details of your item :)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, your table name is `foods`, you can do this with Eloquent or DB facade in your controller.

```
public function search(){
    $foodName = Input::get('food_name'');
    $foods = Food::where('FoodName', $foodName)->get();
    return $foods;
}
```

This is most simple version. I hope it can help.